# Conclude almost sure convergence (not only along a subsequence) from a $L^p$-convergence result

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, almost-everywhere

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a probaiblity space and $A_n,B$ be linear contractions (operator norm at most $1$) on $L^p(\mu)$ for all $p\in[1,\infty]$. Say we know that $$\left\|(A_n-B)f\right\|_{L^p}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag1\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in\mathcal L^p(\mu)\text{ and }p\ge1$$ and $$\left\|(A_n-B)f\right\|_{L^\infty}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in U\tag2,$$ where $U$ is a dense subspace of $\mathcal L^1(\mu)$ with $(A_n-B)U\subseteq L^\infty(\mu)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

If $\delta>0$, we know that there is a $g\in U$ with $$\left\|f-g\right\|_{L^1}<\delta\tag3$$ and $$|(A_n-B)g|\le\left\|(A_n-B)g\right\|_{L^\infty}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\;\;\;\text{on }E\setminus N\tag4$$ for some $\mu$-null set $N$.

> How can we show that $$\mu\left(\left\{\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_nf-\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_nf>\varepsilon\right\}\right)\le\mu\left(\left\{\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left|A_n(f-g)\right|>\frac\varepsilon2\right\}\right)\tag5$$ for all $\varepsilon>0$?

This seems to be an application of a basic inequality, but I can't figure it out. Clearly, by $(4)$, $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_ng=\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_ng\;\;\;\text{on }E\setminus N\tag6$$ and it seems like we need to insert this in $(5)$. Moreover, $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_nf-\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_nf=\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_nf+\limsup_{n\to\infty}(-A_nf)\tag7.$$

Comment: How do you know that $(A_n - B)f \in L^\infty$ for $f \in U \subseteq L^1$? Is there some assumption that is meant to guarantee this? (e.g. it would be enough to assume that $U$ is a subset of $L^\infty$ which is dense in $L^1$ for the $L^1$-norm which seems like a reasonable condition to have in applications)

Comment: @RhysSteele I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. The assumption which guarantees this is $(2)$. I guess I'm missing your point.

Comment: So you're saying that part of assumption $(2)$ is that $(A_n - B)(U) \subseteq L^\infty$? If so that's fine but you should make this clear.

Comment: @RhysSteele Ah, I see. There is a detail missing: It's part of my assumptions that $A_n-B$ maps $U$ to $L^\infty$, right. (I mean, it's somehow clear by the convergence, but strictly speaking I cannot use the norm on $L^\infty$ otherwise ...)

Comment: Can $(2)$ be strengthened at all in your intended application? I'm pretty sure I can make this work if the convergence in $(2)$ is uniform over $L^1$-norm bounded subsets of $U$ but so far can't get anything without such an assumption

Comment: @RhysSteele The desired application is a functional-analytic proof of the pointwise Ergodic theorem which I've found here: https://wt.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/WT/Inhalt/people/Andreas_Eberle/MarkovProcesses1920/MarkovProcesses1920.pdf (step 4 on page 33). However, I don't understand the argument; especially since the invoked Lemma requires $\Theta$ to be $P$-invariant. (In the lecture notes, $B=\pi$ and $U=H_0+H_1$)

Comment: The theorem you're proving there also requires $\Theta$ to be $P$-invariant. You also know a lot more about the operator $A_n$ there. You're more likely to get an answer if you ask about the bit you don't understand in the proof you have for the case you want rather than asking for a proof from scratch of a more general result.

Comment: @RhysSteele Please take note of my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your $(6)$, we have that 
$$\mu\left(\left\{\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_nf -\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_nf>\varepsilon\right\}\right) = \mu\left(\left\{\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_nf - \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n g + \liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n g-\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_nf>\varepsilon\right\}\right).$$

Now, on that set, we have the inequalities
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon <& \limsup_{n\to\infty}A_nf - \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n g + \liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n g-\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_nf
\\ \leq & |\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_nf - \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n g| + |\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n f-\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_ng|
\end{align*}
Therefore, it will suffice to show that $$|\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_nf - \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n g|, |\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n f-\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_ng| \leq \sup_n |A_n(f-g)|.$$

First let's deal with the $\limsup$ term. Since $A_ng$ is a convergent sequence by assumption, we have that 
$$|\limsup A_n f - \limsup A_n g| = |\limsup A_n(f-g)| \leq \sup_n |A_n(f-g)|$$
where the last equality is trivial from the definition of $\limsup$.

The $\liminf$ term can be treated almost identically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer: I think there is a crucial argument missing: While we can always find a subsequence converging to the $\limsup$ (or $\liminf$) of a sequence, you need to argue why your subsequence does not depend on the probability state space $E$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Why? What I'm deriving is a pointwise inequality

Comment: Why do you need to pass to a further subsequence to assume that $A_{n_k}g$ converges? On $E\setminus N$, every subsequence of $A_ng$ should converge. Moreover, since every subsequence converges to the same limit, we should have $\lim_kA_{n_k}g=\lim_nA_ng=\limsup A_ng$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually, we should be able to simply argue that $$\left|\limsup_nA_nf-\limsup_nA_ng\right|=\left|\limsup_nA_n(f-g)\right|\le\limsup_n|A_n(f-g)|=\inf_n\sup_{k\ge n}|A_k(f-g)|\le\sup_n|A_n(f-g)|$$ on $E\setminus N$, where the first equality holds since $A_ng$ converges on $E\setminus N$. (I'm not trying to correct you, but to understand the argument)

Comment: Regarding the generalization I've mentioned before: In a Hilbert space $H$, a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is convergent to $x$ if it weakly convergent to $x$ and $\left\|x\right\|_H\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\left\|x\right\|_H$, but I don't see how we could use this here. Maybe the following idea is more appropriate:

Comment: If I'm not missing something, it is sufficient to show that $(A_nf)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ ($f\in\mathcal L^1(\mu,H)$) is a stochastic Cauchy sequence (since this would imply it is stochastically convergent and hence has an a.s. convergent subsequence which can be identified with $Bf$, since we already know that $A_nf\to Bg$ in $L^1(\mu,H)$). If $\varepsilon>0$, we could clearly write $\mu\left(\left\|(A_m-A_n)f\right|_H>\varepsilon\right)\le\mu\left(\left\|(A_m-A_n)(f-g)\right|_H>\frac\varepsilon2\right)+\mu\left(\left\|(A_m-A_n)Y\right|_H>\frac\varepsilon2\right)$.

Comment: Your first two comments are completely accurate. I'd just forgotten the assumption that $A_ng$ converges on $E \setminus N$ after I'd substituted the equality between the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ into $(5)$ because I suspected the inequality I wanted was true more generally and tried to prove it in that generality; but yes, in this case the proof can be simplified. I'll edit to reflect that now.

Comment: Regarding my Hilbert space comments, I've asked a separate question for that: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3645242/47771.

Comment: Unfortunately, for you last two comments, I can only say that I don't know too much about ergodic theory and so I'm not sure exactly what it is you're trying to get (without spending more time than I have reading through the notes you link). I've been able to take a crack at previous questions because they've been questions in functional analysis/ measure theory but now I'm unsure precisely what the statement of that type you're aiming for is. Edit: I'll take a look at your new question and see if I can help with that

Comment: I don't think that the actual shapes of $A_n$ and $\pi$ are really important (that's why I've omitted them in the other questions). Actually, the whole ergodic theory specific stuff should be unimportant. I'm quite sure that a standard probabilistic argument is sufficient. We just need to find an appropriate replacement for the $\limsup=\liminf$ trick which is used in the $H=\mathbb R$ to conclude the convergence. As I wrote before, showing that $(A_nf)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is stochastically Cauchy ("Cauchy in probability") should be sufficient, since $H$ is complete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107228/discussion-between-rhys-steele-and-0xbadf00d).

Comment: I think there is still a minor issue with the proof: What happens if the expression $\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_nf-\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_nf$ is undefined (e.g. $\infty-\infty$)? Is there something in the setting which ensures that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_nf<\infty$ outside a null set? (and regarding the Hilbert space question: Note that I've missed the crucial point that we first need to find a suitable generalization of the maximal ergodic theorem to a Hilbert space lattice. For example: https://tinyurl.com/yb6b5mx6)

Comment: I've asked for something more general here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3648204/47771.

Comment: You wrote "the $\liminf$ term can be treated almost identically". There you're using the simple inequality $|\liminf A_n(f-g)|\le\liminf|A_n(f-g)|\le\limsup|A_n(f-g)|$, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d The easiest way to see that e.g. the $\limsup$ is finite in your setting is to use the fact that $\limsup A_n g $ exists and the pointwise inequality $|\limsup A_n f - \limsup A_n g| \leq \sup_n |A_n(f-g)|$ I prove (note the proof of that inequality works even if the $\limsup$ is infinite). Then use the maximal ergodic theorem to get control on $\mathbb{P}(\sup_n |A_n(f-g)| \geq c)$ to see that the right hand side is finite a.s. (and your argument for the $\liminf$ works, yes)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Now I was the one who has forgotten that we already know that $\limsup A_ng$ exists ... Do you know if there is a subadditive version of the maximal ergodic theorem?